# Static variable in ActionListener

Tags: java

How to create a variable in ActionListener that its value increases and  leaves saved over all objects(as static variable but ActionListener does not allow to declare it) if the condition is proper?

Comment: Very unclear. But a class is a class is a class. Create a class, add a field to it. Make it implement ActionListener. An ActionListener doesn't **have** to be an anonymous inner class (which, I guess, is what you're doing right now, but you dodn't post any code, so...)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a static inner class instead of an anonymous class:

```
class OuterClass {

    //This static nested class may declare static fields
    private static class MyStaticActionListener implements ActionListener {
        private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your static variable in any class. Then in your ActionListener you just use `ThatOtherClass.staticVariable`. It will work as long as the variable is not private/protected from the ActionListener that is accessing it.